# Dropdown falls behind jPlayer (IE7)

Tags: drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7, z-index, hidden, jplayer

I'm working on a new website re-design; so far every browser compatibility issue has been resolved no problem - but there's one that remains in IE7.

The client has a dropdown menu from the header which extends over the content, but the problem occurs when the client has a related video on the page as this is often displayed first; the video [being displayed just below the header] pushes the menu behind.

The dropdown is created in CSS using a high z-index value (1000).
JavaScript is used to hide and show the menu by altering the 'visibility' value.

The video uses jPlayer, given the age of IE7 it doesn't use HTML5 to display the video but instead includes a .swf file.

---

I have tried altering the z-index of the header, jPlayer, etc to the suggestions on this site but had no luck. I have also tried changing the position from absolute to relative but this broke the dropdown.

I have modified the parameter 'wmode' so that it's property is 'transparent', I've also tried 'opaque'.

The only difference I have made so far is adding hours to the work-log.

---

The page is question can be found here:
http://www.newforest.gov.uk/healthandleisure/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an iframe shim? I had a similar experience with the google earth plugin, and adding the shim to the pieces that need to go on top of the swf elements as:

```
<iframe class="bgi" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="about:blank">
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
</iframe>
```

where bgi is a class that has

```
height:100%;
width:100%;
z-index:-1;
```

Comment: Just tried it and unfortunately had no luck; thank you anyway.